# CSS: Inside a <card> I want an image of max-height, and takes all width without scaling

Tags: css, image

I'm using Bootstrap 4. I have an image inside a card, this image is gonna be card's header:

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top cardimg">
    <div class="card-body">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know ex-ante which are the image's dimensions gonna be, because it is provided by the user, so I want to hava a maximum height of 160, I have tried in the CSS:

```
.cardimg {
    max-height: 120px;
    width: auto;
}
```

And several other versions, this does partly what I want, the header's image is 120px tall. The problem is that the browser scales the width, sometimes it looks more or less fine, sometimes is horrible, depending on the original image height and width.

SO, how can I expand the image to be at most 120px and doesn't scale on the X axis, I don't care if it crops a bit the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Use the `object-fit: cover` property in CSS, so the CSS will be:

```
.cardimg {
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```